# iOS Facebook permissions listed twice on PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, parsefacebookutils

I am using Parse and I am trying to log users in with `PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:block:` method. I am asking only for `user_friends` permission and once, but here is what I'm getting:

[image]

The login process works fine though. Here is my code:

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:@[@"user_friends"] block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if(user){
      ...
    }
}];
```

Is this a framework bug or am I missing something obvious? I am on iOS 8.1 and I have the latest ParseFacebookUtils/Parse pods.

Comment: Where do you get the error or feel like it's error? Please specify.

Comment: @AkshitZaveri Just exactly at the point that I've posted.

Comment: are you talking about "basic profile info"?

Comment: @AkshitZaveri no. I know t's included by default. I am requesting `user_friends` in addition. Please read the alert carefully. it repeats the same permissions twice.

Comment: Oh, that... that is surely bug of SDK. not yours.

Comment: @AkshitZaveri probably. do you know any workarounds though?

Comment: Not possible bro. Sorry to say that.. SDK manages that itself.

Comment: Maybe you can send this details to the Facebook dev team. Or you can wait for someone from Facebook dev team to answer here.!!